# Output results of a MySQL query in JSON by nesting results of a sub query

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

A table is being called from nodeJS and I get the result from the table correctly:

```
            ymvdc_producto   |   ymvdc_imagenes_producto
            ----------------------------------------------
            product 1        |      image product 1 1
                             |      image product 1 2
                             |      image product 1 3
                             |
            product 2        |      image product 2 2
                             |      image product 2 3
```

The result of the table should be the above and the query is

```
        export function listProductos(req: Request, res: Response) {
            //const id_producto = MySQL.instance.conn.escape(req.params.id_producto);
            const objeto = "";
            const query = `SELECT a.nombre_producto,b.id_imagen_producto  FROM ymvdc_producto a
        INNER JOIN ymvdc_imagenes_producto b ON a.id_producto = b.id_producto)`;
        
            MySQL.ejecutarQuery(query, objeto, (error: any, productos: Productos[]) => {
            if (error) {
                res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                warning: "error",
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                ok: true,
                productos: productos,
                });
            }
            });
        }
```

However, I need the JSON output in res.json to be of the type:

```
        {
            "ok": true,
            "productos": [{
                    "nombre_producto": "Producto concreto",
                    "imagenes": [{
                        "id_imagen_producto": "1",
                        "imagen_producto": "imagen 1"
                    }, {
                        "id_imagen_producto": "2",
                        "imagen_producto": "imagen 2"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "nombre_producto": "Producto concreto 2",
                    "imagenes": [{
                        "id_imagen_producto": "1",
                        "imagen_producto": "imagen 1"
                    }, {
                        "id_imagen_producto": "2",
                        "imagen_producto": "imagen 2"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
```

This is the interface:

```
 export interface Productos {
   id_producto?: string;
   id_usuario: string;
   nombre_producto: string;
   descripcion_producto: string;
   id_categoria: string;
   id_subcategoria: string;

   id_imagen_producto: [];
   imagen_producto: [];
 }
```

How should I create the response? Any suggestion?

Comment: *How should I create the response?* Do you want to produce this JSON on MySQL side and save it into the file as-is, or you want to create needed JSON from received data representation on Node.JS?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are asking for formatting that is not available in SQL.  `SELECT` can not (or at least not easily) produce what you show in the `ymvdc_producto` column, namely duplicate values blanked out.

If that is the issue being asked for in this Question, plan on doing it in your Javascript code *after* receiving the results from the database.

A compromise:

```
SELECT ymvdc_producto,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ymvdc_imagenes_producto)
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY ymvdc_producto
```

That will give you

```
     ymvdc_producto   |   ...
     ----------------------------------------------
     product 1        |   image product 1 1,image product 1 2,image product 1 3
     product 2        |   image product 2 2,image product 2 3
```

You may find it easier to use `GROUP_CONCAT`, then split on comma to build the preferred output.